# How to refresh a page in which there's a script for the updating of multiple values just once?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create the script for the editing of profile datas.

I use a POST form, and I check that the new values are different from what is already saved, that is what there is in the session array, and then there's a refresh of the page in order to show immediatly the new values. The problem is that I can't find a way to write just once the refresh of the page:

```
if((isset($_POST['name'])) AND ($_POST['name'] != $profile_name)){

$profile_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);

$update_query = "UPDATE `users` SET `name` = '" . $profile_name . "' WHERE `uid` = '" . $profile_uid . "'";
$update_query_send = mysql_query($update_query);

$_SESSION['name'] = $profile_name;

header('location: #');

}
```

I need to write this code for every variable, for example surname, age and so on, and the refresh is at the end of each one. Is there a way ro refresh the page just once, when all the values are updated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX?

Comment: Because I don't know it ;)

Comment: No, is it impossible to do that just using PHP?

Comment: AJAX will help you update your data without reloading page.

Comment: Jackerbil, you mean that you want to have a php script that tests/saves the name, and then go to another script that saves the surname, and so on?

Comment: Usually, if you have your form/PHP/SQL all inside one page and you want to edit, then echo the results at the same time, you could set another seperate (SELECT) query that will show what's in DB, while using `header('location: file_you_are_using_for_all_this.php');` which is what I use myself.

Comment: Let's say that the script for the updating of profile datas is at the beggining of the page in which there is the form for the updating. So, when the page is opened, it needs to check the values that have been updated, and than refresh to save immediatly the new values in the form for the updating. The question is how to refresh it just ones.

Comment: Ok, well then you could just do a conditional comparison (statement) using `num_rows()` for example, to see if a value already exists in DB. That's if you want to use pure PHP/SQL without Ajax.

Comment: yeah, but suppose that the user updates two values. I would a have a situation like: this value is different and so needs to be updated, and so does this other one. But the refresh is at the end of them both.

Comment: Are your form elements already echoing what's presently in DB?

Comment: Exactly, the values of the form are the onen which are in the db

Comment: Then you shouldn't worry if (one of) the values are the same, unless your column(s) has a `UNIQUE` constraint set to it/them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity sake you could do it like this, set a `$did_update` var to false and then if `did_update`, redirect. Its not optimal as there are other ways which include dynamically building the UPDATE SQL query string to UPDATE once and using AJAX to send the values so as there is no refresh/redirect.

```
<?php 
$did_update = false;

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    //name
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != $profile_name){
        ...
        $did_update = true;
    }

    //surname
    if(isset($_POST['surname']) && $_POST['surname'] != $surname){
        ...
        $did_update = true;
    }

    ...

    //refresh if done update
    if($did_update == true){
        exit(header('location: #'));
    }

}

?>
```